# Combination with Repetition -- Marbles

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let's say that I have 16 marbles, 4 of each of the colors purple, blue, red, and white. I put them in a bowl, pick three randomly, check the colors, and put them back in. How many times do I have to draw from the bowl to guarantee that I'll get 3 of the same color (all purple, blue, red, or white)?

If I were just trying to find the number of distinct possibilities for drawing from the bowl, then I'd have something like C(7, 4) because it would be a combination with repetition problem. However, how would one account for the stipulation that all four must be the same color? It must take considerably more draws than C(7, 4) since there would only be four such cases.

Comment: Can you clarify please. You pick three marbles randomly then put them back and repeat. Do you mean that you keep a tally of the colours picked and you want to know when it's guaranteed that at least one colour will reach 4?

Comment: Pick $3$ and get $4$ of same color? Is this possible?

Comment: @nickgard Sorry about the typo. It should read "get 3 of the same color."

Comment: In that case you're never guaranteed to draw 3 of the same colour, as explained in Toby Mak's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the draws are random:
You can't guarantee an event, much like you can't guarantee that after $1 000 000$ heads, at least one will land on tails. The event has the same probability, and as defined in the meaning of "random event", each draw will have the same probability of occurring (which is not $1$), and there is no guarantee.

Your logic is similar to the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy): that an event will have different odds based on past experiences. But this violates the meaning of probability: an random event with probability $p$ has exactly the same chance of occurring every time.

Hope this cleared some misunderstandings and answered your question.